# Using Python and Selenium, How would I bypass 2 factor authentication?

Tags: python, selenium

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time



x = 0

#while x < 5:

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/John Smith/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/')

x = 0  


def Sign():

    browser.find_element_by_id('signinButton-announce')

    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('signinButton-announce')
    elem.click()

    email = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_email')
    email.send_keys(' ')

    password = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_password')
    password.send_keys(' ')

    SignIn = browser.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit')
    SignIn.click()

def Sign1():

    browser.find_element_by_id('signinButton-announce')

    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('signinButton-announce')
    elem.click()

    email = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_email')
    email.send_keys(' ')

    password = browser.find_element_by_id('ap_password')
    password.send_keys(' ')

    SignIn = browser.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit')
    SignIn.click()
    browser.execute_script("window.open('https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/', 'new window')")
Sign()


time.sleep(20)

browser.execute_script("window.open('https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/', 'new window')")

if (browser.current_url == 'https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/'):
    Sign1()
    x += 1
```

I tried to solve the problem by creating another tab, so if I put in the authentication code once, maybe it would stop asking for it after.  I can't really find a way to solve this.. Is there a way?

I've heard of using a current chrome profile, however I could not find a way to actually use any commands on it.  I've got the chrome file to work, but it would not go to the URL I needed it to go to.